# Why don't carbon nanotubes behave like quantum dots?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, materials, carbon-allotropes, nanotechnology

If carbon nanotubes (CNTs) have the size required to have an bound electron energy state, why don't CNTs behave like quantum dots, such as having optical tunability, amongst other properties?

Comment: What is optical tenability? What other properties you are looking for? Also, have you considered that nanobutes are 1D while quantum dots are 0D structures?

Comment: But somehow they do. It is like asking why a molecule is not a quantum dot. It is, and a very small one. What is more quantum dot than a polyene?

Answer (score 3):

**Carbon nanotubes** are 1-d materials which are confined in 2 dimensions. You cannot compare it with quantum dots which show confinement in 3 dimensions.The difference in optical properties maybe be primarily due to the very small size and 3-D confinement of quantum dots.

Comment: If anything, QDs are 0D, not 3D. Sorry, I don't find this answer to be convincing or comprehensive.

Comment: @Isaac said that the confinement is 3D (ie the structure is a 0D)